More swap on zfs architecture
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 and choosed encrypted zfs architecture to set compression.
But I need more swap, by default it installed Ubuntu 24.04 with 4gb. I would need much more, at least 16gb.
This is what I have for now:

How to increase the Partition 3 which I guess is my swap partition.
In /etc/fstab I have:
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-CRYPT-PLAIN-dm_crypt-0 none swap sw 0 0

I would prefer to avoid a swap file on a compressed file system...
